# How to correctly shutdown a rosnode?

Tags: ros, rosout, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I test a simple code snippet:

```
import rospy
import time
import sys
if __name__=="__main__":
  rospy.init_node("a node")
  rospy.signal_shutdown("an exception")
```

this code will cause /rosout create a file descriptor leak, check with:

```
lsof -n | grep rosout
```

which shows a line  "rosout    111215          13u     sock                0,8       0t0    797756 can't identify protocol".

Each time the code is executed, one more file descriptor leak will be created.

How to prevent this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250494/how-to-correctly-shutdown-a-rosnode?/) by [nansmallgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28852/nansmallgong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-21**:
This looks like a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/250393/rosout-leaks-file-descriptors/

**Comment by [nansmallgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28852/nansmallgong/) on 2016-12-21**:
That question is also posted by me, an established socket should be listed like
"rosout    111215 111574    10u     IPv4             794212       0t0       TCP 127.0.0.1:40341->127.0.0.1:39110 (ESTABLISHED)", but by no means "can't identify protocol".

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2016-12-30**:
Hi nansmallgong, can just show me your launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I found a tricky solution for the problem.

just sleep for seconds before calling the rospy.signal_shutdown methods

```
import rospy
import time
import sys
if __name__=="__main__":
  rospy.init_node("a node")
  time.sleep(1)
  rospy.signal_shutdown("an exception")
```

---

Originally posted by [nansmallgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28852/nansmallgong/) with karma: 26 on 2016-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-02**:
This is actually a file descriptor leak caused by a bug in roscpp. I have a proposed fix here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1214